# Filter whole line from output in command line

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, mysql, grep

I'm trying to find a bottleneck caused by some MySQL query, which oftentimes overloads the web server. Then I found this useful command:

```
mysqladmin -u myusername -p -i 1 processlist
```

which every second, a table with all the active processes in MySQL is printed, including vital information such as the SQL query, and the number of seconds it's taking, like in this screenshot:

[image]

This has proven very useful in most cases. But the problem now is on a client who experiences this problem about once or twice an hour. Then this solution is like searching for a needle in a haystack.

So, what I would like to achieve, is to print every line where I get 5 or more seconds, the whole line.

The only thing I got close to what I need is adding grep to the output like this:

```
mysqladmin -u digitalasesores -p -i 1 processlist | grep '| 5    |'
```

but obviously this is not what I want since it will display only when a query reaches 5 seconds. Is it possible to filter by any number from 5 on?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not using slow query log?

Comment: What's the slow query log you're talking about?

Comment: It logs queries that take longer than x seconds to a log :)

Comment: I didn't even know it exists! I've just found more info about it in Google, so I will do a more thorough research. Thank you!